Spring Boot Processing huge Excel Files
I need assistance with an issue regarding Java heap memory error on our Dev AKS (Kubernetes) environment. The code runs smoothly on my local machine, but when deployed to AKS, which handles files with more than 500 thousand records (over half a million), I encounter this error.
I've attempted to address this by increasing the memory allocation using -Xmx3G configuration in my application YAML file, but the problem persists. To further troubleshoot, I reduced the processing to only 50 thousand records, and everything worked as expected.
Below is my code
IOUtils.setByteArrayMaxOverride(950_000_000);
    log.info("Processing input stream....");
    Workbook workbook = null;
    try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
        log.info("Creating workbook from input stream");
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        log.info("Getting workbook....");
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Check the first column header
        Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
        log.info("Validating file headers....");
        if (firstRow != null && firstRow.getCell(0) != null &&
                firstRow.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().contains("Table")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file format please make sure to delete first 3 rows of the file");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IOException("Error processing Excel file.", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (workbook != null) {
                workbook.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            log.error("Error closing workbook.", ioException);
        }
    }

Below is my application.yaml config
spring:
  datasource:
    # overridden by executen environment SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
     #    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/materialdb
    #    username: dummy
    #    password: Welcome123
   driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
   testWhileIdle: true
   validationQuery: SELECT 1
tomcat:
  default-auto-commit: false
hikari:
  auto-commit: false
  connectionTimeout: 300000
  idleTimeout: 120000
  maximumPoolSize: 20
  minimumIdle: 20
  leakDetectionThreshold: 0
  jpa:
show-sql: false
hibernate:
  ddl-auto: update
  naming:
    implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
properties:
  hibernate:
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
main:
  jvm:
    additional-options: "-Xmx3G"


You say that this is deployed to AKS which I assume is Azure. It is kind of strange to me that the question then only focuses on Spring Boot. Azure is where the memory limits of containers are configured.

Hey @Gimby, I've set memory limits, but the issue persists. Could it be that my nodes don't have enough memory?
